# Negativity of a quadratic polynomial

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we are given

$P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

and we want to ensure that, for all positive reals $x>0$, we have
$$
P(x)<0.
$$

Is it sufficient to ensure that the discriminant $b^2-4ac<0$?

---

Negative discriminant means that there exists no real $x$ such that $P(x)=0$.

But how to ensure $P(x)<0$?

Comment: $a < 0$ and $\Delta < 0$ are equivalent to $P(x) < 0$ on the whole $\mathbb{R}$ but if you only want $P(x) < 0$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$, you can find other examples like $P(x) = -(x + 1)(x + 2)$.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought $x$ was arbitrary.

Comment: I would like to have the statement for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and for positive reals.

Comment: I see that $\Delta <0$ and $a<0$ means that the polynomial is positive on whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What if I only want $P(x)<0$ for $x\geq 0$?

Comment: @Tim No, EG $-x^2 + 100x - 1$

Comment: (I withdraw my classification because there are additional cases to include. Basically you look at the turning point, and figure out what additional conditions you need)

Comment: $a<0$, $c<0$, $b<\sqrt{4ac}$ or $a<0$, $c=0$, $b\leq 0$ or $a=0$, $b<0$,$c\leq 0$ or $a=0$,$b=0$, $c<0$ is enough for $P(x)$ to be $<0$ for all $x>0$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case where we have a quadratic, so $a \neq 0$

Clearly we have the necessary conditions of

- $P(\infty) < 0 \Rightarrow a < 0 $
- $P(0) \leq 0 \Rightarrow c \leq 0$

For sufficiency, consider cases depending on where the vertex is located

1. If the vertex's x-coordinate  is negative or 0 $(b \leq 0)$, then those conditions are sufficient.
2. If the vertex's x-coordinate is positive ($ b > 0$) ,then we require that the discriminant is negative ($b^2 < 4ac$).

I leave the linear case $a = 0$ to you, and you can use similar ideas above.

Comment: What about $a=0$?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Left as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: @DavidK Not quite. Then you miss the case of $ a < 0, b = 0 , c  = 0 $. (The issue is that when $ c = 0 $, we have equality, but when $c < 0$, we have strict inequality. Hence, it's not that easy to combine the conditions without overly complicating it)

Comment: Right, my $b<$ condition could fail when $b=0$. So it seems there's no avoiding alternate conditions.

Answer (score 0):

As OP wants the conditions for both positive real number $\mathbb{R}^{+}$  and for all real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, I think it is useful to provide more details and discuss the both cases for $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $\mathbb{R}$. The following is mainly for all real number part. Also, some details for $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ is added.

---

> Given $P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. Assume $a\neq 0$ for keeping $P(x)$ a quadratic equation. Find the necessary and sufficient conditions for $P(x)<0$, where the domain is $\mathbb{R}$

---

> $$P(x)=ax^2+bx+c=a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2- \frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}=a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2- \frac{D}{4a}$$,
> where $D=b^2-4ac$.

From this expression, we can see that:

- $P(0) =c$
- $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} P(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
           +\infty & \mbox{if $a >0$};\\
          -\infty & \mbox{if $a < 0$}.\end{array} \right.$
- The vertex is at $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$, with value $P(-\frac{b}{2a})=- \frac{D}{4a}$. It is a maximum point if $a<0$ and a minimum point if $a>0$.

> $D\geq 0$ if and only if there exists at least one real root for $P(x)=0$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

The domain $\mathbb{R}$ here is important so that $D<0$ is a necessary condition for this question on domain $\mathbb{R}$. Since we can have real roots on $\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ and $P(x)<0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$, $D<0$ is not a necessary condition for this question on domain $\mathbb{R}^{+}$.

---

For the necessary conditions,

if $P(x)<0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then

- $P(0)<0 \Rightarrow c < 0$
- $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} P(x)<0 \Rightarrow a < 0$
- $P(-\frac{b}{2a})=- \frac{D}{4a} < 0 \Rightarrow D<0 $ (as a < 0)

For sufficiency part, if $a<0$ and $D<0$, then we have
$$P(x)=a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2- \frac{D}{4a}<0$$

Note that if $D=b^2-4ac<0$, then we have
$$a<0 \text{ if and only if } c<0 .$$

So the necessary and sufficient conditions for $P(x)<0$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is either
$$a<0 \text{ and } b^2-4ac<0$$
or $$c<0 \text{ and } b^2-4ac<0$$

---

Now discuss the $\mathbb{R}^+$ part:

> Given $P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. Assume $a\neq 0$ for keeping $P(x)$ a quadratic equation. Find the necessary and sufficient conditions for $P(x)<0$, where the domain is $\mathbb{R}^+$

if $P(x)<0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$, then only this condition holds immediately,

- $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} P(x)=-\infty \Rightarrow a < 0$

As $c=P(0)$, it is not necessary $c<0$ now. In fact, it is necessary that $c\leq 0$.

- Claim $P(0)\leq 0$. Suppose $P(0)> 0$, by continuity of $P(x)$, there exists $x_0>0$ s.t. $P(x_0)>0$, contradicts to $P(x)<0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

Also, it is not necessary that $P(-\frac{b}{2a})< 0$ unless $b>0$ (the vertex is at $x=-\frac{b}{2a}\in \mathbb{R}^+$).

So if $b>0$, then $P(-\frac{b}{2a})=- \frac{D}{4a} < 0 \Rightarrow D<0 $ (as a < 0)

For sufficiency part, divide into two cases:

1. $a<0, b>0, D<0$
2. $a<0, b<=0, c<=0$

Case 1: $a<0, b>0, D<0$ (it is similar to the case for domain=$\mathbb{R}$)
$$P(x)=a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2- \frac{D}{4a}<0$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$

Note: c cannot be 0, i.e. $c<0$.

Case 2: $a<0, b<=0, c<=0$
$$P(x)=ax^2+bx+c<0$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$

So the necessary and sufficient conditions for $P(x)<0$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ is either
$$a<0, b>0, D=b^2-4ac<0$$
or $$a<0, b<=0, c<=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Because polynomials are continuous, by the intermediate value theorem we have that $P(x)$ takes on both positive and negative values if for some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $P(x_0)=0$. Conversely, if there does not exist such an $x_0$, then $P(x)$ is strictly nonzero positive or strictly nonzero negative. To figure out which, we can look at either $a$ or $c$. If either of these is less than $0$, then $P(x)<0$ for all $\mathbb{R}$.

So, $P(x)<0$ for all $\mathbb{R}$ if either of the following holds:

$b^2-4ac<0$ and $c<0$

$b^2-4ac<0$ and $a<0$

If we restrict the domain to positive reals, then we need $a,b,c<0$.

Comment: $-x^2 - 100x - 1$ would contradict your classification, since $b^2 - 4ac > 0 $.

Comment: But it doesn’t satisfy the negative discrimination property

Comment: Note that $(b^2-4ac<0 \land c<0) \iff (b^2-4ac<0 \land a<0)$, so you only need consider one of those two conditions.

Comment: For the domain of positive reals, also consider $-x^2+x-100$, for which $P'(0)=1$.

Comment: As in, $ - x^2 - 100x - 1$ is negative on the positive reals so we're interested in it, but it doesn't fall into your classification because it doesn't satisfy the negative discriminant property. Hence, your classification is incomplete.  $\quad$ The error with your reasoning is that we could have $P(-100) > 0 $, while still allowing for the value on the positive reals to be negative.